# Linear CSS color gradient with radial alpha/transparency gradient?

Tags: css, gradient

I'm not sure how to achieve that. I need to have a left-to-right color gradient with radial gradient so that both extreme ends are gradually fading away. Is that even possible?

My linear color gradient CSS is as follows:

```css
div {
  background: rgb(5, 75, 135);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(5, 75, 135, 1) 24%, rgba(166, 40, 46, 1) 69%);
  
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)? Use a `radial-gradient` as the `<image>`: `mask: radial-gradient(circle at center, #fff 30%, #fff0)`.

Comment: @InSync Thank you, I will look into that. I'm fairly new into CSS/HTML stuff. Have no idea how to do what you just said.

Comment: What do you mean by "*have no idea*"? `mask` is a normal CSS property, so just use it like you would with any other properties.

Answer (score 0):

this would help: `background: radial-gradient( rgba(5, 75, 135, 1) 10%, rgba(166, 40, 46, 0.7) );`

Comment: But wouldn't this mean the color gradient will be linear, too?

Comment: nah, it would be radial with a center color, and a surround color which is fading.

Comment: That is the problem. I need to keep the linear color gradient but apply on it a radial alpha gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for. You can achieve linear-gradient and radial-gradient using `background-blend-mode`
`linear-gradient(to right....` and `radial-gradient(at left...` or vice-versa according to your need

```css
div.one {
  background: rgb(5, 75, 135);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(5, 75, 135, 1), rgba(166, 40, 46, 1)), radial-gradient(at left, rgba(5, 75, 135, 1), transparent);
  height: 3em;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}



div.two {
  background: rgb(5, 75, 135);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(5, 75, 135, 0), rgba(5, 75, 135, 1), rgba(166, 40, 46, 1), rgba(166, 40, 46, 0)), radial-gradient(at left, rgba(5, 75, 135, 1), transparent);
  height: 3em;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<br>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I basically need the image to fade into invisibility on the right and on the left, so that the extreme left/right ends are invisible.